# Strange path for the offline image

Tags: file-upload, path

I'm working in Joomla 4.
For a few weeks now, when I want to insert an image in an article, the path to the folder where the image is located is strange and looks like this:

images/stories/logo-shop.png****#joomlaImage://local-images/logo-shop.png?width=600&height=232****

I'd like to know why

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**NEWFORMAT**

that is new security or enhanced feature, if you look on

```
#joomlaImage
```

there is many posilibilitys word in there which tell you source of image, exp
in local folder or outsite url, then you can apply the condition ref="dofollow" on **img>a href** or another condition base on that value.

By default, Joomla 4 also use the witdh or height attribut in url query string

```
//local-images/logo-shop.png?width=600&height=232
```

you can use that value to minimize CLS score and get SEO benefit on loading image.

the truely source of image is still before `"#"

```
images/stories/logo-shop.png
```

**CUSTOMIZE**

you also do custom for this on source

```
libraries/src/form/field/mediafield.php
```

on respective function **getLayoutData()**.
but, any modified to this source will gone by update.

**PERMANENT TWEAK**

the form responsiblity the image on content is on **adm/component/com_content/form/article.xml**

Joomla defaultly not allow us to modified them, you can see many plugins to secondly add the form on them

the image form is

```
<field
    name="image_fulltext"
    type="media"
    label="COM_CONTENT_FIELD_FULL_LABEL"
/>
```

you can see the type="media" on that the type value has origin source on

`libraries/src/form/field/mediafield.php`

so you also make your own form library on that folder, exp name **CustomMediaField.php** which source come from **mediafield.php**, but overriding getLayoutData() function with your own code, then get the value on type to `type="custommedia".`